# My web application is running on One Server and two worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, 502-error

my nginx config file is

server {
        listen ip-address:80 ;

```
      server_name subdomain.domain.com;
        server_name www.subdomain.domain.com;
        server_name ipv4.subdomain.domain.com;

location / {
proxy_pass http://ip-address:32038/;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

proxy_http_version 1.1;


  fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
}


}
```

server {
         listen ip-address:443 ssl http2;

```
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
server_name www.subdomain.domain.com;
server_name ipv4.subdomain.domain.com;

ssl_certificate /opt/psa/var/certificates/scf83NyxP;
ssl_certificate_key /opt/psa/var/certificates/scf83NyxP;
ssl_client_certificate /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfrr8L8y;

proxy_read_timeout 60;

location / {
  proxy_pass https://ip-address:30588/;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

}

my website on http://subdomain.mydomain.com is running fine . but when i use https://subdomain.mydomain.com it displays bad gateway error page server by nginx

through ssh when i run following command everything works fine

For http
curl -v -HHost:subdomain.mydomain.com http://ip-address:32038

curl -v subdomain.mydomain.com

For https
curl -v -HHost:subdomain.mydomain.com https://subdomain.mydomain.com:30588

From server node SSH
curl -v -HHost:subdomain.mydomain.com --resolve subdomain.mydomain.com:30588:ip-address --cacert /opt/psa/var/certificates/scf83NyxP https://subdomain.mydomain.com:30588

curl -v -HHost:subdomain.mydomain.com --cacert /opt/psa/var/certificates/scf83NyxP http://ip-address:32038

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, welcome to Serverfault. Please explain what exactly are you trying to accomplish with your configuration. How Kubernetes comes into play here as it's not mentioned inside your post?